# WPF - same style of contexmenu on different operating systems

Tags: wpf, styles, contextmenu

Is there any way to force a `ContextMenu` to look the same in every operation system (Windows XP Win7 Windows Vista)?

I installed my small application on windows xp and the `ContextMenu` looks totaly different than I expected. It seems thatthe  `ContextMenu` gets its look from windows style or something like that. So is there any way to force this `ContextMenu` to get the style which I want?

Maybe somebody has a good looking style for `ContextMenu` (in XAML).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see for instance [here](http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!199.entry). Basically you need to explicitly load the correct theme, which is in this case PresentationFramework.Aero.dll//themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml .